# Sort a List by attribute but keep order of same attributes

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have a list that could look like this:

`{A[1], A[2], B[1], A[3], B[2], B[3], A[4]}`

whereas `A,B` is an **attribute** of object in the list.
The numbers indicate **the order** of the objects related to each other with the same attribute.

---

Now, I want to sort the list so that I have the following result:

`{A[1],A[2],A[3],A[4],B[1],B[2],B[3]}`

---

In concrete, this means the order of the objects related to each other object with the same attribute should stay the same, but the general order should be by the attribute. The problem is that the order related to each other is not determinable by an additional attribute, it is just specified by the order in the root list.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `List.sort` method to sort all the elements based on the **attribute** value.

Elements with same attribute value will remain in the same order they have been inserted.

For instance:

```
@Test
public void testSortList() {

    List<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Element("A", 1));
    list.add(new Element("A", 2));
    list.add(new Element("B", 1));
    list.add(new Element("A", 3));
    list.add(new Element("B", 2));

    list.sort((element1, element2) -> element1.getValue().compareTo(element2.getValue()));

    assertThat(list.get(0).getValue()).isEqualTo("A");
    assertThat(list.get(0).getPosition()).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(list.get(1).getValue()).isEqualTo("A");
    assertThat(list.get(1).getPosition()).isEqualTo(2);
    assertThat(list.get(2).getValue()).isEqualTo("A");
    assertThat(list.get(2).getPosition()).isEqualTo(3);
    assertThat(list.get(3).getValue()).isEqualTo("B");
    assertThat(list.get(3).getPosition()).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(list.get(4).getValue()).isEqualTo("B");
    assertThat(list.get(4).getPosition()).isEqualTo(2);
}
```

Where `Element` class looks as follow:

```
class Element {

  /** Attribute used to sort the elements */
  private String value;

  /** Attribute used to remember the original position of this element in the list */
  private int position;

  public Element(String value, int position) {
    this.value = value;
    this.position = position;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public int getPosition() {
    return position;
  }

  /** Insert equals and hashCode! */
}
```

Comment: Thank you, did not know that the insertion order is implicit using the list sort!

Comment: Be careful.  It depends on the List implementation. ArrayList is an ordered list

Answer (score 1):

Just define a new comparator specifying in it your requirements: check if objects have the same attribute, and in that case specify the priority on the base of the position in the rootlist; otherwise, order by the attribute itself.

```
Collections.sort(rootlist, new YourComparator());

class YourComparator implements Comparator<YourClass> {
    @Override
    public int compare(YourClass a, YourClass b) {
        if(a.attribute == b.attribute){
            return rootlist.indexOf(a) < rootlist.indexOf(b) ? -1 : rootlist.indexOf(a) == rootlist.indexOf(b) ? 0 : 1;
        }
        else 
            return a.attribute < b.attribute ? -1 : 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Does the sort-method of Collections make a copy of your list for sorting (and applies the values afterwards) or does it sort the list directly. Because in the second case, it might change the ordering of elements with the same attribute without comparing them directly (depending on the algorithm, e.g. it compares first and last element at one point). In the second case your solution might not work!

Comment: From the docs: "This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the corresponding position in the array". So shouldn't be the case. In any case, you can pass a copy of your rootlist to Collections.sort if this is an issue.

Comment: Ok, then it should do the job. If you pass a copy, this wouldn't change the issue, since then the comparator looks at the (maybe changed) copied list. But since the docs stated it makes a temporary copy, this should be the best solution.

Comment: I meant pass a copy (by values, not another reference to same list) to sort method but still use original list in Comparator.compare(). But in any case shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if the already implemented method `list.sort()` maintains your condition, so I would suggest you the simple sort with O(n²) calculations, assuming your `compare`-method returns 0, if the attribute is the same:

```
List<T> sortList(List<T> list){
    for(int ind=1; ind<list.size(); ind++){
        for(int indBack=ind; indBack>0; indBack--){
            if(compare(list.get(indBack), list.get(indBack-1))==1){
                T tempSave = list.get(indBack-1);
                list.set(indBack-1, list.get(indBack));
                list.set(indBack, tempSave);
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [stable sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts).

Don't know whether Java inbuilt methods use some stable sort (like TimSort). If not, you easily may find Insertion Sort or Merge Sort implementation.